# UI in Linux has random stutters with x11 on nvidia. Wayland is buttery smooth but has bugs

Tags: linux, x11, nvidia, wayland, lag

I've been using GNU/Linux for the past 4 years now, and am closely following the progress of stuff like Wayland and Nvidia support. I think the progress achieved last year is awesome. Wayland however isn't stable enough for daily use at the time of writing this.

I've had random stutters in x11 since forever (mostly when dragging windows and some animations) and I've been looking for a fix for as long as I've used GNU/Linux. So far the only solution I've seen work for me is using Wayland/XWayland. I recently got a 165hz monitor and the difference is even more noticeable and it freaks me out. I can't wait for Wayland to be more stable but until then I've got to use x11. So, is there anything I can do to improve/fix the random UI stutters? I'm using the latest Nvidia proprietary driver but I've seen no difference when using older versions.

I also have "Prefer Maximum Performance" in nvidia-settings. This also happens with any DE I've tested.

Note: When I say stutters what I'm really saying is when moving an application window it looks like the window would render at 165 fps and randomly drop to <= 60 for a few seconds and then go back to normal.

Comment: This sounds like your compositor bug.

Comment: It sounds like your problems are purely cosmetic not functional. That's pretty much the way Linux is. I find Wayland with gnome 3 in Debian Bullseye to be perfectly stable. But I don't pay attention to the screen image while moving a window. Call me weird, blind, or whatever. It simply doesn't affect me. For operating-system prettiness I think Windows 10/11 wins hands down against Linux. And, setting for maximum performance is not the way to get what you're seeking. Try maximum quality.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like what I've been experiencing.  After some digging, I found a patch for mutter and after adapting the patch for the current version of mutter, building and installing, everything is smooth again.

I wrote up a how-to targeted at Ubuntu 22.04, but even if you're not using that (mutter-42.9), you should be able to adapt the patch for your mutter version.  This should help, at least: https://stuffivelearned.org/doku.php?id=os:linux:ubuntu:nvidiastutter